# Sampling in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, random

I am looking for possible ways of random sampling in PostgreSQL. I found a couple of methods to do that with different advantages and disadvantages. The naive way to do that is:

```
select * from Table_Name
order by random()
limit 10;
```

Another faster method is:

```
select * from Table_Name
WHERE random() <= 0.01
order by random()
limit 10;
```

(Although that 0.01 depends on the table size and the sample size; this is just an example.)

In both of these queries a random number is generated for each row and sorted based on those random generated numbers. Then in the sorted numbers the first 10 are selected as the final result, so I think these should be sampling without replacement.

Now what I want to do is to somehow turn this sampling methods into sampling with replacement. How is that possible? Or is there any other random sampling method with replacement in PostgreSQL?

I have to say that I do have an idea how this might be possible but I don't know how to implement it in Postgres. Here is my idea:

If instead of generating one random value we generate `S` random values where `S` is the sample size, then order all of the random generated values, it will be sampling with replacement. (I don't know if I am right.)
At this point I don't mind about the performance of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres 9.3+, you can use the folowing:

```
select t.*
from 
  generate_series(1, 10) as x(i)
    cross join lateral
  ( select *, x.i
    from Table_Name
    -- where random() < 0.01
    order by random()
    limit 1 
  ) ;
```

which basically chooses 1 random row, 10 times.

---

In older versions, you can use a simple `cross join` (no `lateral`):

```
select t.*
from 
    generate_series(1, 1000) as x(i)
  cross join 
    Table_Name as t
    -- where random() < 0.01
    order by random()
    limit 10
  ) t ;
```

which creates a 1000-fold copy of the table (so each row is there 1000 times) and then chooses 10 rows with the same method as your query. If the number of copies (1000) is large enough compared to the wanted rows (10), the probabilities are almost equal to the probabilities you would have got with replacement.

Performance of this second query will of course be horrible, even with small tables.

Answer (score 4):

#### Corrective

> If instead of generating one random value we generate S random values
> where S is the sample size, then order all of the random generated
> values, it will be sampling with replacement. (I don't know if I am right.)

You are wrong in two points.

1. Your original query does not generate "one random value". `random()` is a volatile function that is called for *every row*. Then all rows are sorted by the result, that's why this is hugely inefficient for big tables.
2. Accordingly, the approach "if we generate `S` random values ..." is going nowhere. You have to "granulate" random rows to matching "row numbers" - either existing IDs or surrogate numbers. That's what I am going to demonstrate.

I know you said:

> At this point I don't mind about the performance of the query.

So [@ypercube's answer is correct](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/96612/3684) as usual. But my heart is bleeding. There are *much* faster ways.

Assuming the **worst case** that you don't know *anything* about the table.

Attach a sequential number to each row in arbitrary order, then you can select random rows reliably, multiple times if you want. The table is scanned once, which is *still expensive* for huge tables and small samples, but much better than scanning *n* times:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT *, row_number() OVER () AS rn FROM tbl)
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT trunc(random() * (SELECT max(rn) FROM t))::int + 1 AS rn
    FROM   generate_series(1, 10) g
    ) r
JOIN   t USING (rn);
```

Each row has the same chance to be selected any number of times.

If you have an ID column with few or no gaps there are much faster options for big tables:

- [Best way to select random rows PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8675160/939860)

Comment: Nice. I knew there must be a more efficient method than mine!

Comment: Is there any way to do sampling on time series data in postgresql based on fixed time interval?
Like, we are having 1-1 record per second for 24 hours. Means approx 86400 records are there. Is there any simpler way to get every 10 sec data point? (Should return 8640 records)

Comment: @Yash: There are various ways. Please ask your question as *question*, providing all relevant details of your setup and requirements. Comments are not the place.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Please refer https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/285217/time-based-sampling-in-postgresql for detailed question.